# Detecting tennis court lines intercepts

Tags: python

I am trying to improve my code to find the tennis court line intercepts so that I can find the boundaries of the different quadrants of the court.

[This is the tennis court image I am trying to analyze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlLrx.jpg)

[This is the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vjzx.png)

I achieved this by first finding the white pixels in the image, then applying canny edge detection with some preprocessing such as Gaussian blur. Then the canny edge output is dilated to help prepare it for hough lines detection.

Then taking the hough lines output I used the python implementation of the  [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](https://github.com/ideasman42/isect_segments-bentley_ottmann) by github user ideasman42 to find the hough line intercepts.

This seems to work pretty well, but I'm struggling to tune my system to find the last 4 intercept points. If anyone could give me advice to improve or tune this implementation or even offer up some ideas for a better way to solve the problem of finding the court boundaries I would appreciate it.

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import  poly_point_isect as bot

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# define the list of boundaries
boundaries = [
    ([180, 180, 100], [255, 255, 255])
]

# loop over the boundaries
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
    # the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    # show the images
    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(output,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)

low_threshold = 10
high_threshold = 200
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)
dilated = cv2.dilate(edges, np.ones((2,2), dtype=np.uint8))

cv2.imshow('dilated.png', dilated)
cv2.waitKey(0)

rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 10 # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 40  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 5  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
line_image = np.copy(output) * 0  # creating a blank to draw lines on

# Run Hough on edge detected image
# Output "lines" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilated, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)

points = []
for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        points.append(((x1 + 0.0, y1 + 0.0), (x2 + 0.0, y2 + 0.0)))
        cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 5)        

cv2.imshow('houghlines.png', line_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

lines_edges = cv2.addWeighted(output, 0.8, line_image, 1, 0)
print(lines_edges.shape)

intersections = bot.isect_segments(points)
print(intersections)

for idx, inter in enumerate(intersections):
    a, b = inter
    match = 0
    for other_inter in intersections[idx:]:
        c, d = other_inter
        if abs(c-a) < 8 and abs(d-b) < 8:
            match = 1
            if other_inter in intersections:
                intersections.remove(other_inter)
                intersections[idx] = ((c+a)/2, (d+b)/2)

    if match == 0:
        intersections.remove(inter)

for inter in intersections:
    a, b = inter
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            lines_edges[int(b) + i, int(a) + j] = [0, 0, 255]

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('line_intersections.png', lines_edges)
cv2.imwrite('line_intersections.png', lines_edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Is this code finished? The images you posted makes it look like it is, but your last paragraph indicates that it is incomplete and you are looking for help to get the last few intercepts, in which case it would be off topic here.